# Apply borderRadius on bottom tab bar

Tags: react-native

I want to apply radius on bottom tab bar, but on background I have a white view. How can I remove this white view?

```
const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeScreenStack,
    // ArchiveScreenStack,
    // SettingsScreenStack,
    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style:{borderRadius:21, backgroundColor:"#000000"}
        }
    }
)
```

[Screen of bottom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWmr9.png)

Answer (score 6):

In the screenOptions of <BottomTabs.Navigator> there is a option of tabBarStyle, define it like this

```
tabBarStyle: {
                backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.accent500,
                paddingTop: 7,
                borderTopLeftRadius: 24,
                borderTopRightRadius: 24,
                borderLeftWidth: 0.2,
                borderRightWidth: 0.2,
                position: 'absolute',
                overflow: 'hidden',
},
```

**Now you will have rounded corners in bottom tab and also there won't be any background white color**

NOTE: screenOptions prop is present in React Navigation v6, for other versions there is prop but with different name, so explore the doc for other versions

Hope this will help you or somebody else...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the white space using style

```
const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeScreenStack,

    },
    {
        tabBarOptions: {
            style:{
              borderTopLeftRadius:21, 
              borderTopRightRadius:21,
              backgroundColor:"#000000",
              position:'absolute',
              bottom: 0,
              padding:10,
              width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
              height: 54,
              zIndex: 8 
           }
        }
    }
)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It works! But there is now another problem: i can't use the bottom tab bar. All bottomtab's route are untouchable. If i remove position:'absolute', it works but i have again the white space on background

Comment: you'll need `zIndex` so that the bottomtab will be on top of everything else. updated my answer, sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

Wrap <Tab.Navigator> with a view and style it with the backgroundColor you want ex.:

```html
<View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
  <AppTabs.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarStyle: {
        borderTopLeftRadius: 24,
        borderTopRightRadius: 24,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        height: 68
      }
    }}>
    <AppTabs.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  </AppTabs.Navigator>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it:

```
<Tab.Navigator
   tabBarOptions={{
      borderTopLeftRadius: 40,
      borderTopRightRadius: 40,
      marginTop: -40,
    }}
```

This will make the background be the screen. However you will also need to add a marginBottom:40 to each of your screens so that any components can be fully viewed.

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarOptions={{
        showLabel: false,
        activeTintColor: 'white',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        style: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
          borderTopRightRadius: 25,
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: 0,
        },
      }}
```